# Hi Folks replace the null values with max value in the table and add 1 to the max value

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Can any one help me on this

my source table is like this

```
col1
-----
123
456
---
---
459
---
461
```

but i want target like this

```
col1
-----
123
456
457
458
459
460
461
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is ex contain a primary id number datatypes and col1 number datatypes.

```
select 
nvl(col1,
    nvl(
      (select col1+1 from ex i where i.id = o.id-1),
      (select col1+2 from ex i where i.id = o.id-2))
    ) from ex o;
```

If you notice there's a pattern in the sql. You can refactor that to a function. To see an example output here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c37be/3).